# iGraph incidence matrix

Tags: r, networking, igraph

I'm a newbie to iGraphs - trying to draw an incidence matrix (matrix with every node and every edge and 1;s, 0's and -1's to indicate whether an edge originates, does not connect to or terminates at a particular node.

Here's a simple worked example with a dataframe - 5 nodes, 10 edges,

```
r <- 5
borders <- data.frame(permutations(5,2))
borders <- borders[c(seq(1,nrow(borders), by = 2)),]
colnames(borders) <- c("head", "tail")
borders$cap <- rnorm(n = nrow(borders), mean = 5, sd = 2)
network <- graph.data.frame(borders) 
plot(network)
as_incidence_matrix(network)
```

And here's the result:

```
Error in as_incidence_matrix(network) : 
  Not a bipartite graph, supply `types' argument
```

This must be about the simplest thing to do with igraphs - anyone have a very quick steer or fix - I guess I am using the wrong function.

Answer (score 1):

The as_incidence_matrix() is only for bipartite networks, and the example you provided is not one.  Instead you could try using the intergraph function to convert the igraph object to a network object and use the as.matrix function to convert it to an incidence matrix.  Try this,

```
library(intergraph)
library(network)
as.matrix(asNetwork(network),matrix.type="incidence")
```